# Массив указателей и работа с ним в С#

Tags: c#, массивы, указатели

Добрый вечер,

есть код:

```
int *[]  a;//массив указатилей
int kol = 5;
a = new int*[kol];
int[] some = new int[kol];
//тут мы заполняем левыми данными some, пускай это будут числа 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

далее хочу взять и в каждое a[i] положить указатель на some[i]

```
for(int i=0;i<kol;i++)
    a[i] = &(some[i]);
```

пытался так же

```
for(int i=0;i<kol;i++)
    a[i] = some+i;//как бы some возвращает указатель на 0 эл.
```

так как же сделать, чтобы мы в наш массив указателей могли перенести указатели на элементы массива some?
З.Ы. Стоит задача чтобы был класс, а в нём массив указателей на int-ы. поэтому конструкцию fixed не знаю, как сюда вставить.

Comment: `a[i] = &some[i];` - так не работает?

Comment: А причём тут C#? У вас в коде чистый C.

Comment: @VladD, https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y31yhkeb.aspx

Comment: @DenisBubnov: О боже! Это реально unsafe-код? о_О

Comment: @VladD, никогда не подумал бы, что кому-то пригодится такое в C#...но вот и увидел. Как-то ради интереса даже пробовал подобное. Странно, но автор не отвечает на комменты...

Comment: @DenisBubnov: Вангую, что автору это тоже не нужно, а нужен на самом деле C++ :-P

Comment: @VladD, мало ли. Автор вроде бы уверенно написал и в наименовании вопроса и в тегах **C#**. Посмотрим, что будет. Либо unsafe, либо правда плюсы.

Comment: просто никто не отвечал, вот и ушёл от компа)

Comment: unsafe включён, а в с++ и сам отлично знаю как подобное сделать, но вот именно необходимо данное реализовать в #

Comment: А почему бы не использовать nullable версию `int?`, в вашем случае `int? []` и работать с обычными для C# ссылками? Это конечно снизит производительность за счет боксинга, но тут уже от задачи зависит, иногда этим можно пренебречь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fixed` по синтаксису похож на `using`, только предназначен для закрепления (pin) объекта в куче и получения указателя на этот объект. Закрепление необходимо, потому что объект может быть перемещен сборщиком мусора и полученный ранее указатель станет не валидным. После выхода из блока `fixed` объект снова становится доступен для сборщика.

Пример:

```
int kol = 5;
int*[] a = new int*[kol];
int[] some = new int[kol];

fixed (int *p = some) {
    for (int i = 0; i < kol; ++i) {
        some[i] = i + 1;

        // Элементы массива располагаются в памяти непрерывно
        // Как и в С, sizeof(int) при сложении учитывается
        a[i] = p + i;

        Console.WriteLine("Address: 0x{0}, Value: {1}", new IntPtr(a[i]).ToString("X"), *a[i]);
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
Address: 0xFF1E0D99C8, Value: 1
Address: 0xFF1E0D99CC, Value: 2
Address: 0xFF1E0D99D0, Value: 3
Address: 0xFF1E0D99D4, Value: 4
Address: 0xFF1E0D99D8, Value: 5
```

Вы упомянули, что хотите создать класс, в котором будет поле с массивом указателей. Здесь нужно быть осторожным, поскольку вам придется держать закрепленным массив `some` как минимум так же долго, как будет использоваться массив указателей на него (что более вероятно - так же долго, как существует экземпляр класса, особенно если `some` передается в него откуда-то извне). Если через `fixed` это будет трудно сделать, то используйте [GCHandle.Alloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1246yz8f(v=vs.100).aspx) с типом `GCHandleType.Pinned`.